Looking for title of 80's thriller
I remember watching some probably R rated movie in the mid 80's when I was 6 or 7 on HBO but don't know the name of it.  Here is all I can remember:

Bad guys are chasing some small boy (maybe 11 or 12) and trying to
shoot/kill him.  Lots of shootouts and he is able to keep evading
them.
At some point near the end he meets up with his dad?/guardian and I
vaguely remember someone becoming invisible. Also something about a
tape recording and I think the final setting was an airport.

Does anyone know this?

Any other detail would help, even if it seems minor. Do you remember the kid's hair color or where the chase took place? Was the invisible character a ghost, perhaps?

My first thought was Cloak & Dagger, starring Dabney Coleman.  It somewhat fits the profile, with an 11-year-old boy caught up in espionage, and his "savior/partner" is an imaginary guy.  At the end, he meets his real dad in an airport, if memory serves me correctly.

Yes I believe that's the one I was thinking of
